# Having a button react to tap

Tags: ios, swift

In my `UICollectionView`, I have a `UICollectionReusableView` - a header - that contains a `UIButton`. I want it to do something when tapped, but unfortunately I also have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` attached to the collectionView, which intercepts any tap gestures on all views in the collectionView.

How might I be able to respond to the button tap without throwing away the gesture recognizer?

Comment: I thought this "just worked"? See "Interacting with Other User Interface Controls" on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html